# Problematic frame: # V libjvm.so+0x5c73c5

Tags: java, linux, jvm, webmethods

Need help to understand below issue. Java used within one of webMethods Servers crashes frequently with below fatal error -

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f25a13633c5, pid=6307, tid=0x00007f2584efe700

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_141-b15) (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.141-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
V  [libjvm.so+0x5c73c5]  G1ParScanThreadState::copy_to_survivor_space(InCSetState, oopDesc*, markOopDesc*)+0x45
```

No specific error is logged in wrapper logs, happens once a week since last 1 year.

---

**Edit:** adding information from comments

Adding few key parameters from custom_wrapper.conf for reference -

```
wrapper.java.additional.206=-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 
wrapper.java.additional.207=-XX:+UseG1GC wrapper.ping.timeout=0 
wrapper.java.initmemory=5120 wrapper.java.maxmemory=8192 
wrapper.java.additional.4=-XX:MaxPermSize=1280M
```

Looking for any suggestions/changes in wrapper.conf that may solve this, thank you.

Comment: Adding few key parameters from custom_wrapper.conf for reference -          
wrapper.java.additional.206=-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200
wrapper.java.additional.207=-XX:+UseG1GC
wrapper.ping.timeout=0
wrapper.java.initmemory=5120
wrapper.java.maxmemory=8192
wrapper.java.additional.4=-XX:MaxPermSize=1280M

Looking for any suggestions/changes in wrapper.conf that may solve this, thank you.

Shreyus

Comment: Looks like a heap corruption issue. This could be caused by anything: unsafe application code, bad libraries or a JVM bug. Can't say more without seeing the complete crash report and preferably a test case that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Java was upgraded recently from build 1.8.0_71-b15 -> build 1.8.0_141-b15, hoping the upgrade would solve it but it did not. Test case - we are not able to replicate it as we dont know what is causing it. Happens at 3 windows mainly.. 7/15/17 CET.. no DB extensive integrations are executed at those times & no jobs at OS layer also found that could be causing it..

Comment: i can share the latest error dump 'hs_err_pid6307.log' from 21st Nov, where can i upload?

Comment: Possibly https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8156137 ?